# Replace NaNs for month N with the value for month (N - 1) in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

I have some pricing data for parts that updates monthly. It has been pulled into a pandas dataframe. Occasionally, a part won't get a price for a certain month, in which case I would like to replace it with that part's price from the previous month.

In the event that the previous month also has a missing price for that part, I want to continue searching backwards until a valid price is found, in which case this price should propagate forward until a valid price is found.

If no valid prices are found for that part, then I want this part to be dropped from the dataframe entirely.

If the first number of months contain missing prices for a certain part, I would like to delete these rows so that the first record is always a valid price.

Essentially I want to do a forward fill on the price column but taking part numbers into account.

As an example, I would start with something like this:

```
part   price      date
1      NaN        2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
3      99.16      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1      NaN        2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
3      NaN        2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
1      67.32      2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
3      167.34     2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
3      212.70     2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
3      NaN        2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
2      NaN        2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
3      264.02     2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
1      NaN        2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

And end with this:

```
part   price      date
1      67.32      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
3      99.16      2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1      67.32      2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
3      167.34     2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
1      67.32      2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
3      167.34     2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
3      212.70     2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
3      264.02     2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
1      88.37      2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
3      264.02     2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
df.loc[lambda df: df.groupby('part')['price'].transform(np.any)]\
  .sort_values('date')\
  .assign(price=lambda df: df.groupby('part')['price'].ffill())\
  .dropna()\
  .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result:

```
    part    price   date
0   1   88.37   2018-07-01
1   3   264.02  2018-07-01
2   1   88.37   2018-08-01
3   3   264.02  2018-08-01
4   1   88.37   2018-09-01
5   3   212.70  2018-09-01
6   1   67.32   2018-10-01
7   3   167.34  2018-10-01
8   1   67.32   2018-11-01
9   3   167.34  2018-11-01
10  1   67.32   2018-12-01
11  3   99.16   2018-12-01
```

A little more details:

- The first line of the method chain removes any rows whose part numbers don't have a non-null price for any date
- The next line sorts the values by date
- The 3rd line replaces the `'price'` column with a forward-filled one by group
- The 4th line drops rows with nulls
- The final line is just for looks

If you want the `df` in the order you showed, you can flip the dataframe:

```
df = df.iloc[::-1].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use bfill rather ffill here:

```
In [11]: df.groupby('part')['price'].bfill()
Out[11]:
0      67.32
1        NaN
2      99.16
3      67.32
4        NaN
5     167.34
6      67.32
7        NaN
8     167.34
9      88.37
10       NaN
11    212.70
12     88.37
13       NaN
14    264.02
15     88.37
16       NaN
17    264.02
18       NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

So update the price column:

```
In [12]: df['price'] = df.groupby('part')['price'].bfill()

In [13]: df
Out[13]:
    part   price                     date
0      1   67.32  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
1      2     NaN  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
2      3   99.16  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
3      1   67.32  2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
4      2     NaN  2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
5      3  167.34  2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
6      1   67.32  2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
7      2     NaN  2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
8      3  167.34  2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
9      1   88.37  2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
10     2     NaN  2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
11     3  212.70  2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
12     1   88.37  2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
13     2     NaN  2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
14     3  264.02  2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
15     1   88.37  2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
16     2     NaN  2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
17     3  264.02  2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
18     1     NaN  2018-06-01 00:00:00.000
```

Now you can drop those with NaN price:

```
In [14]: df = df.dropna(subset=['price'])

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
    part   price                     date
0      1   67.32  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
2      3   99.16  2018-12-01 00:00:00.000
3      1   67.32  2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
5      3  167.34  2018-11-01 00:00:00.000
6      1   67.32  2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
8      3  167.34  2018-10-01 00:00:00.000
9      1   88.37  2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
11     3  212.70  2018-09-01 00:00:00.000
12     1   88.37  2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
14     3  264.02  2018-08-01 00:00:00.000
15     1   88.37  2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
17     3  264.02  2018-07-01 00:00:00.000
```

Answer (score 0):

With your data in a dataframe (df) as shown above in your question, you can use the following to get your result:

```
df = df.pivot_table('price', index='date', columns ='part').fillna(method='ffill')
df.dropna().sort_index(ascending=False)
```

In my case your answer is in a pivot table however.

```
   part       1       3
date        
2018-12-01  67.32   99.16
2018-11-01  67.32   167.34
2018-10-01  67.32   167.34
2018-09-01  88.37   212.70
2018-08-01  88.37   264.02
2018-07-01  88.37   264.02
```